# Converting Django BooleanField to NullBooleanField and changing default

Tags: django

I need to change a field from

```
my_boolean = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Safe Visiting Space", default=False)
```

to

```
my_boolean = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name="Safe Visiting Space", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

So I've made the above change within the model and run makemigrations to create

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0164_auto_20201027_0820'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='my_boolean',
            field=models.NullBooleanField(default=None, verbose_name='Safe Visiting Space'),
        ),
    ]
```

But this will not set the default of the current 70k records to None but will leave them as False, so I amended the migrations file to

```
from django.db import migrations, models

from my_app.models import MyModel

def set_my_boolean_default(apps, schema_editor):
    objects= MyModel.objects.active().filter(my_boolean=False)
    for object in objectss:
        object.my_boolean = None
        object.save()
        
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('providers', '0164_auto_20201027_0820'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='organisation',
            name='infection_control_safe_visiting_space',
            field=models.NullBooleanField(default=None, verbose_name='Safe Visiting Space'),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(set_my_boolean_default),
    ]
```

This will take hours to run.  Also, a random check of the database and it doesn't seem to be updating any of the records.

What is the right / better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking you so long because of this for loop:

```
    objects= MyModel.objects.active().filter(my_boolean=False)
    for object in objects:
        object.my_boolean = None
        object.save()  # Database roundtrip
```

Namely, for each object, you are hitting the database. The better way is to `bulk_update` the fields all at once:

```
objects= MyModel.objects.active().filter(my_boolean=False).update(my_boolean=None)
```

You can perform the query above inside your shell. It's better not to include it in your migration files for it may be executed each time you run migrations.

Enter you `Django` shell by `python manage.py shell`, import your model, and execute the query above.